# How to handle private state in functional programming?

Tags: kotlin, functional-programming, rx-java, state

I have a feature in my application which has some private state information and some public state to share. How can I get rid of the mutable private state variable? How do I get the private state into the chain?

I just recently learned about functional programming and wanted to transform this feature to a more fp-like approach.

This is my approach so far as a simple example.

```
sealed class PublicState {
    data class Data(val a:Int, val b:Int):PublicState()
    object Pending : PublicState()
}

data class PrivateState(val a:Int, val b:Int, val x:Int)

sealed class Action {
    data class InputC(val c:Int):Action()
    data class InputD(val d:Int):Action()
}

sealed class Update {
    data class A(val a:Int):Update()
    data class B(val b:Int):Update()
    object Working : Update()
}

class Feature {

    val actions = PublishSubject.create<Action>()
    val state = BehaviorSubject.create<PublicState>()

    private var privateState = PrivateState(0,0,1)

    init {
        val startState = privateState.toPublicState()
        actions.flatMap {action ->
            when (action) {
                is Action.InputC -> handleC(action)
                is Action.InputD -> handleD(action)
            }
        }.scan(startState, ::reduce)
            .subscribe(state)
    }

    fun reduce(previousState:PublicState, update: Update):PublicState {

        // can't use previousState because Pending has not all information
        // I don't want to add the information to pending because state is undefined while pending
        return when (update) {

            is Update.A -> privateState.copy(a = update.a).toPublicState()
            is Update.B -> privateState.copy(b = update.b).toPublicState()
            Update.Working -> PublicState.Pending
        }
    }

    fun doAction(action: Action) {
        actions.onNext(action)
    }

    private fun handleC(action:Action.InputC):Observable<Update> {
        return Observable.fromCallable {
            // time consuming work which uses x
            val result = privateState.x + privateState.a + action.c
            Update.A(result) as Update
        }.startWith(Update.Working)
    }

    private fun handleD(action:Action.InputD):Observable<Update> {
        return Observable.fromCallable {
            // time consuming work which uses x
            val result = privateState.x + privateState.b + action.d
            Update.B(result) as Update
        }.startWith(Update.Working)
    }

}

private fun PrivateState.toPublicState(): PublicState {
    return PublicState.Data(a, b)
}
```

In reality there are a lot more state variables than a, b and x. But if I want them in the chain, I have a gigantic State variable and all of it gets exposed. It feels easier with the mutable variable.
Do you have any suggestion how to solve this? I am also open for other patterns, if you think this is a wrong approach.
My goal is to keep some private state and expose just the PublicState.

Comment: I take it you are attempting a Model-View-Intent pattern? In your example (using the rx scan function) you should be using the `previousState` and returning a new immutable state, as progressive steps, rather than always using your `privateState` in `::reduce`.  That is the attraction of the `scan` operator for this usecase (internally in the `Observable` last emitted item will be stored).  IMO I feel that MVI pattern has some major flaws that aren't addressed in the examples - having one entry point to the View entices mixing state with events, to me the two can be mutually exclusive.

Comment: Private state isn't really compatible with functional programming. Private state is a solution to a problem you don't really have if you're e.g. using immutable data structures and exporting lenses for access. But that being said, why do you feel the need to alter this particular code if it's working?

Comment: @MarkKeen Yes, it is a modification of the MVI pattern. If I use `previousState` in `::reduce` I can't access the state if it is in `Pending`. Do you have an example for the major flaws in MVI? At the moment I really like MVI, but I am open minded for other patterns, which one would you recommend?

Comment: @JaredSmith I want to experiment with different patterns and I like the ideas of functional programming, so I wanted to try it out. I don't need to change it. I just want to find "my style"

Comment: The Android platform offers `ViewModel` which lends itself to a MVVM architecture - https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel  You can obviously use any architecture or design pattern, I don't have any bad examples of MVI but I would say that any "pattern" that tightly couples itself to a library can be less flexible.

Comment: @Runje I haven't seen your codebase beyond what you posted, but I would guess that there's almost certainly some lower-hanging fruit. Pick something smaller scale to start with.  Also it isn't clear why there needs to be any private state at all in your example since you're abstracting everything with Observables. As Mark Keen already suggested, I don't see anything going on there that couldn't be accomplished with rx operations alone, although that's kind of tangental.

Answer (score -2):

FP does not deal with private states. Why would you care about keeping something private? Because someone else, from an outer world, could intentionally or not **mutate** that one and bring entire object into disrepair, right? But there are no mutations in the FP. So you're safe.

Thus your quesiton reduces to the "how to handle state". Well, let me know if you want me to answer.

Comment: How about because if you have a nested data structure then exposing it gives an implied contract to your users that the structure will never change and creates brittle APIs? Immutability isn't enough. Lenses exist for a reason.

Comment: @JaredSmith, surely you're right, but this kind of problems are far beyond basics. OP author "just recently learned about FP", so I see no use in going deep into advanced stuff. The other fact to consider is that the question was precisely about private state and it came from the OOP-view; lenses have little to do with mental shifting, which is a key here.

Comment: @SerejaBogolubov My idea was to expose only these things which are being used by the consumers of the class. Ideally expose for each state only the information needed. `Pending` has no additional Information and `Data` has Information `a` and `b`. But then I can not use the `previousState` in `::reduce`, because Pending has not all the information. How would you handle the state in this case?

Comment: @JaredSmith How can i cross the streams to achieve my goal? Can you give me a hint?

Comment: @Runje Mark Keen already did in the comments. Look in to the Rx `scan` operator. I mean, realistically, you could complete rewrite this code to be some sort of 'Haskell-in-Kotlin' if you really really wanted to, but it would be way easier to just read/example-code your way through the Rx docs.